# Button subtract and add from value only affect one

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to add and subtract from a value without it affecting the other number when I have more than 1 module.

Check out the Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/puJ6G/1007/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate each set of controls. To do this I added a containing `div`:

```
<div class="count-container">
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' data-field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' data-field='quantity' />
</div>
```

You can then find this container using `closest()` and then the `input` to update using `find()`:

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(this).closest('.count-container');
    var $field = $container.find('input[name=' + $(this).data('field') + ']');
    var currentVal = parseInt($field.val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $field.val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        $field.val(0);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/puJ6G/1010/)

Also, note that I amended the invalid `field` attribute to `data-field`, to prevent any odd behaviour from the DOM.

Comment: You "can", not you "need"

Comment: @singe31 Fair point. However, I would argue this method is more semantic that using `next()`/`prev()`. Especially if you end up moving around the HTML.

Comment: Yes, I prefer this method

Comment: This would be the way I would do it too - if the op is able to change the html structure

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Is it possible to have not no go beyond 0? I would like it to stop at 0

Comment: You just need to add a condition on the minus action: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/puJ6G/1015/

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var fieldName = $(this).data('field');
        var input = $(this).prev('input[name='+fieldName+']');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
            input.val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var fieldName = $(this).data('field');
        var input = $(this).next('input[name='+fieldName+']');
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            input.val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            input.val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/1009/)

You will also note that I have changed your `field` attributes to `data-field` as this allows you to make use of jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function rather than adding invalid attributes to your inputs

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises from your `name` attribute on the input element.
All of your input elements have the same `name` value of `quantity`, hence when using the selector `$('input[name='+fieldName+']')` you are receiving a reference to **all** inputs with the same name.

There is several options to remedy the issue.

You could give all related inputs a unique `name`, preferably a GUID, similar to this:

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='9056FF9E-E3ED-4F35-9E82-73796E80EA12' />
<input type='text' name='9056FF9E-E3ED-4F35-9E82-73796E80EA12' value='0' class='qty' />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='9056FF9E-E3ED-4F35-9E82-73796E80EA12' />
<br>
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='B0B852FB-75B5-4C54-B403-A09AA75A961B' />
<input type='text' name='B0B852FB-75B5-4C54-B403-A09AA75A961B' value='0' class='qty' />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='B0B852FB-75B5-4C54-B403-A09AA75A961B' />
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cof1enbf/) - Using unique names

---

You could simply use jQuery's `next()` and `prev()` functions, ignoring the `name` attributes (**assuming the HTML is not going to change**), similar to this:

```
$(this).prev().val(...); // for +
$(this).next().val(...); // for -
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vqeLza7/) - Using `next()` and `prev()`

---

You could also add a contextual element, grouping the relevant elements and use jQuery's `parent()` and `.find()` functions, similar to:

```
$(this).parent().find('input[name='+fieldName+']');
```

There is more ways of solving this off course.

Answer (score -1):

i have updated your code..

code:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // This button will increment the value
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        //the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        // Get its current value
        var txt=$($(this).prev("input[type=text]"));
        var currentVal = parseInt(txt.val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
          txt.val(currentVal + 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
            txt.val(0);
        }
    });
    // This button will decrement the value till 0
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');

         var txt=$($(this).next("input[type=text]"));
            // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt(txt.val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            txt.val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            // Otherwise put a 0 there
           txt.val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/1011/

thanks